# O que é que o operador ">" faz no meio de uma expressão aritmética em C++?

Tags: c++, operadores, sintaxe

Encontrei esta linha de código em um solução proposta para um certo problema.

```
excedente = a % 10 + b % 10 + excedente > 9;
```

A minha questão é, que função é que o `> 9` faz nesta linha me específico?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esse é o operador relacional de "maior que", igual o que tem na matemática, então ele compara o operando que está à esquerda com o operando que está à direita e resulta em um valor booleano, ou seja, ou o resultado será falso ou verdadeiro, não pode ser outra coisa, portanto a variável `excedente` é do tipo `bool` e terá o valor `false` ou o valor `true`.

Note que a expressão da esquerda é toda operação matemática `a % 10 + b % 10 + excedente`, já que a precedência deste operador é menor do que os demais operadores usados, e tem associatividade da esquerda para a direita, então podemos ler assim:

```
excedente = ((a % 10 + b % 10 + excedente) > 9);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/GratherThan.cpp).

E claro, ele quer saber se aquele cálculo da esquerda é maior que 9.

Comment: Nunca tinha visto um exemplo deste tipo. Obrigado !

Comment: Extremamente comum.

Comment: Eu ainda estou aprendendo C++. Toda ajuda é essencial.